# select statement without using Top keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT TOP 2 * FROM Customers;
```

How to find top 2 records in sqlserver 2008 without using Top Keyword

Comment: What's problem with above query..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
SET ROWCOUNT 2
SELECT  * FROM Customers
ORDER BY 1 asc
```